# parse user agent with Ragel

Tags: regex, ragel

I have the following line from apache (changing the apache log format is not an option):

```
... referrer=- user_agent=JSON-RPC Client status=200 size=44 ...
```

and I am trying to parse it with Ragel. I am getting all the fields extracted except the user_agent. The user guide says that strong difference `--` ensures that the first machine does NOT contain the second. In my case, I want to match anything that does not contain `" status="`, which would signify the next field. However, my current definition (below) appears to be skipping `user_agent` entirely; I still get `status` and following fields. Am I utilizing strong difference properly?

```
...
referrer   = ^space+             >mark %{ emit("referrer"); };
user_agent = any* -- ' status=' >mark %{ emit("user_agent"); };
status     = digit+              >mark %{ emit("status"); };
...

line = ( 
  ... 
  space "referrer=" 
  referrer 
  space "user_agent="
  user_agent
  space "status="
  status
  space "size="
  ...
);
```

Comment: Suggestion - make this question  strictly a regex problem, without considering Ragel as a programming language. There are more specialists on regex here than on Ragel. Unfortunately, it's not clear to me on what you want to do. Please include some sample inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I'm just getting into Ragel and this may help others.

The problem here is operator precedence. The action operators `>` and `%` are evaluated before the strong difference operator `--`. It's easy to fix with parentheses:

```
user_agent = (any* -- ' status=') >mark %{ emit("user_agent"); };
```

I would also use `space` instead of hard-coding a space, at least for consistency:

```
user_agent = (any* -- (space 'status=')) >mark %{ emit("user_agent"); };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use state charts, try this state machine:

```
STATUS := digit+ ' ' @{ fnext SIZE; };
SIZE   := digit+;

USER_AGENT =
    start: (
        's'    -> s1 |
        [^s] @{ if (!ua_start) ua_start = p; }  -> start
    ),
    s1: (
        't'  -> s2 |
        [^t] -> start
    ),
    s2: (
        'a'  -> s3 |
        [^a] -> start
    ),
    s3: (
        't'  -> s4 |
        [^t] -> start
    ),
    s4: (
        'u'  -> s5 |
        [^u] -> start
    ),
    s5: (
        's'  -> s6 |
        [^s] -> start
    ),
    s6: (
        '='  @{ fnext STATUS; ua_stop = p - 7; } -> final |
        [^=] -> start
    )
    ;

main := "user_agent=" USER_AGENT ;
```

U can get the user agent in "ua_start" -> "ua_stop", for other variables, i think u already knew how to mark & get the characters.